# How can I suppress the space between generated arguments during brace expansion?

Tags: bash, zsh, brace-expansion

I used the following command to create a list of URLs that I want to test:

```
echo -e localhost:8080/reports/{promos,promo-updates,scandown}/{130,139,142}{,-unburdened,-burdened}{,.pdf,.xls,.xlsx,.csv,.preload}"\n" >> urls.txt
```

Unfortunately the URLs appended to `urls.txt` each had a space before them (except for the first, of course).  I understand why that happened, and I realize I could just strip it off by piping throug a `sed` expression, but I'd like to know if there's a way to suppress it instead.  (It may seem silly and pedantic, but it's no different than the preference so many people feel for [not "abusing cats"](http://devmanual.gentoo.org/tools-reference/cat/).)

I tried [double-quoting to suppress word-splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting), but that suppressed the brace expansion too, so that was a no-go.

I tried changing IFS to an empty string, but it didn't work either:

```
IFS='' echo -e localhost:8080/reports/{promos,promo-updates,scandown}/{130,139,142}{,-unburdened,-burdened}{,.pdf,.xls,.xlsx,.csv,.preload}"\n" >> urls.txt
```

Nor did changing it to a newline:

```
IFS='\n' echo -e localhost:8080/reports/{promos,promo-updates,scandown}/{130,139,142}{,-unburdened,-burdened}{,.pdf,.xls,.xlsx,.csv,.preload}"\n" >> urls.txt
```

Comment: Are you using bash or zsh?

Comment: at the moment I'm using bash (I'm at work) but on my own laptop I use zsh.  I was expecting brace expansion to work identically in both, but perhaps that's not the case.

Comment: In that case Gnouc answer will be the most compatible with different shells.

Comment: Wouldn't richard's answer be equally compatible?  (It also has the advantage of being simpler, therefore I don't have to stop and think about the fiddly bits the next time I want to use it.)  On the other hand, Gnouc's answer is also excellent.  And I think I learned the most from glenn jackson's answer. Leiaz's answer seems simplest and most elegant, but of course is zsh-only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could store the brace expansion in an array, then output it in the manner of your choosing:

```
urls=( localhost:8080/reports/{promos,promo-updates,scandown}/{130,139,142}{,-unburdened,-burdened}{,.pdf,.xls,.xlsx,.csv,.preload} )
```

Then

```
printf "%s\n" "${urls[@]}"
```

or

```
(IFS=$'\n'; echo "${urls[*]}")
```

The echo example looks weird because:

1. it's run in a subshell (the parentheses) so I don't alter my current value of IFS.
2. IFS needs to be defined in a separate command:

   - This doesn't work: `IFS=$'\n' echo "${urls[*]}"` because the variable gets expanded before the new env variable takes effect
   - IFS needs to be set *before* you start expanding variables.

Also, note the subtle difference in the dereferencing array index used:

- `[@]` in the printf example to expand the array into individual words
- `[*]` in the echo example to expand the array into a single word, with elements separated by the first char of IFS

Comment: It's a hard call, but I'm choosing this answer because (1) it seems (AFAIK) to be the closest to the stated goal of suppressing rather than merely removing the spaces, and (2) I learned the most from it (a stated goal of my question).

Answer (score 17):

Use `printf` builtin:

```
$ printf %s\\n localhost:8080/reports/{promos,promo-updates,scandown}/{130,139,142}{,-unburdened,-burdened}{,.pdf,.xls,.xlsx,.csv,.preload}
localhost:8080/reports/promos/130
localhost:8080/reports/promos/130.pdf
localhost:8080/reports/promos/130.xls
localhost:8080/reports/promos/130.xlsx
localhost:8080/reports/promos/130.csv
localhost:8080/reports/promos/130.preload
localhost:8080/reports/promos/130-unburdened
localhost:8080/reports/promos/130-unburdened.pdf
localhost:8080/reports/promos/130-unburdened.xls
localhost:8080/reports/promos/130-unburdened.xlsx
localhost:8080/reports/promos/130-unburdened.csv
localhost:8080/reports/promos/130-unburdened.preload
....
```

Answer (score 6):

This is tagged zsh, so I suggest the zsh builtin `print` :

```
print -l localhost:8080/reports/{promos,promo-updates,scandown}/{130,139,142}{,-unburdened,-burdened}{,.pdf,.xls,.xlsx,.csv,.preload}
```

`-l` prints arguments on separate lines.

Comment: +1 Thanks--good to know!  I'll use that when I'm on zsh.  I tagged it that simply because I use both and both support brace expansion.  (I don't know if any others do, but I find ksh terribly confusing, so I stay away.)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the brace expansion is adding the space, and echo is adding the newline. So using single responsibility principle, handle the newline separately.

```
echo -e localhost:8080/reports/{promos,promo-updates,scandown}/{130,139,142}{,-unburdened,-burdened}{,.pdf,.xls,.xlsx,.csv,.preload} | tr " " "\n"
```

Comment: I think this is the simplest and most practical approach

Comment: No, brace expansion is not adding the space, it's creating several arguments to `echo`. That's `echo` that prints its arguments separated by spaces.

Comment: I guess the problem occurs because `echo` separates arguments by spaces and the newline is inserted additionally __before__ each space instead of replacing the space (which would be more sensible). From memory, `xargs` has a known issue very similar to this one (especially with the `-0` option)